# Hide Navigation Bar in Android

Tags: java, android, navigationbar

I hope that someone can help me.

I am developing an Android Game in Java and I need to hide the navigation bar of the main screen, but I can not find any solution to this. I have searched for a lot of information, even I checked the solutions proposed here, but nothing.

I have built my map in a layout (**juego.xml**) and then I used it in a java class which extends from a view **(VistaJuego**). Additionally in this class I define another class called **ThreadJuego**. The objective of this class is to run indefinitely a method which update the physics of the game.

Finally I have another class called **Juego** which extends from AppCompactActivity. This last class load an instance of Vistajuego.

Find below the definition of the classes and layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.richard_tfg.tankgame.VistaJuego
    android:id="@+id/VistaJuego"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/mapa_batalla2">

</com.richard_tfg.tankgame.VistaJuego>
```

This is the code of the layout. Below I will post an example of VistaJuego:

```
 public class VistaJuego extends View {
  

    private ThreadJuego thread = new ThreadJuego();
    /* Do more things */

    public VistaJuego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    /*Definitions of graphics*/
    
    }


    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    /* Definitions*/
    ...
    ...
    ...
    thread.start();
    }
   

    protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        /*Definitions*/
     }

    private void setFeatures(Grafico grafico, int angulo, int rotacion){
    /*Definitions*/
    }

     protected synchronized void actualizaFisica(){
     /*Update physics*/
     }


   

     class ThreadJuego extends Thread{
    
    
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    actualizaFisica();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Finally the code of my class Juego:

```
public class Juego extends AppCompatActivity {

 VistaJuego vistaJuego;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.juego);
        vistaJuego=findViewById(R.id.VistaJuego);

    }
}
```

I am trying to hide the navigation bar with the line:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); but it still keeps on the screen.
```

Additionally I have tried to use the next method:

```
private void hideStatusAndNavBar() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    );
}
```

and called it on the onCreate method of Juego class, but if I do this I have 2 different behaviors on my devices:

1. Honor 9X: I can see that the navigation bar is hidden but all the grapichs are mixed in a corner and the behavior of app is strange.
2. Samsung S10: The app always fails and the problem I can see on the Log in Android Studio is related with the definition thread.start(); I do not why the problem is the Thread...

I have searched a lot of information but nothing works, so if someone can help me with this, I will be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Call this method in your onCreate

```
private void hideSystemBars() {
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat controller = new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(
        getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView()
    );
    
    controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
    controller.setSystemBarsBehavior(
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    );
}
```

imports

```
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsControllerCompat;
```

This method will hide the nav bar, and show it when the user swipe the zone of the nav bar .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a proffesional/experienced android dev but something like this might be useful for you:

```
        // removal of status and navigation bar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
        fullscreenContent.windowInsetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
    } else {
        // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
        // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
        // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
        fullscreenContent.systemUiVisibility =
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
```

You can add this code in your "OnCreate" method where "fullscreenContent" is the layout holding all your screen data which in your case should be a layout containing "VistaJuego" that you might need to add to the xml file because I don't recommend you to use the root framelayout for this purpose.

Comment: Btw sorry I didn't notice yours is java, I sent this in kotlin but it is easily convertable to java code as you know